# Three.js “webgl-template.html:69 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'domElement' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, web, three.js

I'm trying to run this code I downloaded from https://www.benzedrine.ch/3D-ODRPP.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0056)https://www.benzedrine.ch/vistaprint/webgl-template.html -->
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: #000000;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        canvas {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="info">info</div>

    <script src="/js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
            varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
            void main() {
                vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
                vWorldPosition = worldPosition.xyz;
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            }
        </script>
    <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
            uniform vec3 topColor;
            uniform vec3 bottomColor;
            uniform float offset;
            uniform float exponent;
            varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
            void main() {
                float h = normalize( vWorldPosition + offset ).y;
                gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( bottomColor, topColor, max( pow( max( h , 0.0), exponent ), 0.0 ) ), 1.0 );
            }
        </script>
    <script>

        var container, camera, controls, scene, renderer;
        var mesh;

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            controls.update();

        }

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
            camera.position.set(411, 218, 559);

            /*
                            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
                            controls.damping = 1.0;
            */
            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
            controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
            controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
            controls.noZoom = false;
            controls.noPan = false;
            controls.staticMoving = true;
            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.15;
            controls.addEventListener('change', render);

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xffffff, 1, 5000);
            scene.fog.color.setHSL(0.6, 0, 1);

            var geometry;
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x1ec876 });

            //XXX

            var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.6);
            hemiLight.color.setHSL(0.6, 1, 0.6);
            hemiLight.groundColor.setHSL(0.095, 1, 0.75);
            hemiLight.position.set(0, 500, 0);
            scene.add(hemiLight);

            var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
            dirLight.color.setHSL(0.1, 1, 0.95);
            dirLight.position.set(-1, 1.75, 1);
            dirLight.position.multiplyScalar(50);
            scene.add(dirLight);

            var groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10000, 10000);
            var groundMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ ambient: 0xffffff, color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x050505 });
            groundMat.color.setHSL(0.095, 1, 0.75);

            var ground = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, groundMat);
            ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
            ground.position.y = -0.1;
            scene.add(ground);

            var vertexShader = document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent;
            var fragmentShader = document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent;
            var uniforms = {
                topColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0x0077ff) },
                bottomColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff) },
                offset: { type: "f", value: 33 },
                exponent: { type: "f", value: 0.6 }
            }
            uniforms.topColor.value.copy(hemiLight.color);

            scene.fog.color.copy(uniforms.bottomColor.value);

            var skyGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(4000, 32, 15);
            var skyMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({ vertexShader: vertexShader, fragmentShader: fragmentShader, uniforms: uniforms, side: THREE.BackSide });

            var sky = new THREE.Mesh(skyGeo, skyMat);
            scene.add(sky);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color, 1);

            container = document.getElementById('container');
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
            animate();

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            render();

        }

        function render() {

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        init();
        render();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And I got this error

> webgl-template.html:69 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'domElement' of undefined
> at init (webgl-template.html:69)
> at webgl-template.html:154

this is the code in line 69

controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

Please help me. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please don't add multiple language tags. Just use the tag for the language that you're using.

Comment: Tks @Scheff, I'm not really familar with web development so... My bad ! I'll be better in the future

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is you are using the variables before you actually initialize them, so you get an error that says can not read property of **undefined**. In javascript the variables will have a value of undefined if you don't initialize them.

```
var foo; 
foo.bar; // You can't do this because foo is undefined
```

In your example you have to do initialization of the `renderer` variable before you use it. And since you use the variable `scene`, you also have to initialize it.

So that's the working code:

```
function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xffffff, 1, 5000);
    scene.fog.color.setHSL(0.6, 0, 1);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color, 1);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
    camera.position.set(411, 218, 559);

        
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    ...
```

Remember if you don't have THREE.js locally you have to download it or use the url for the libraries. Like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Happy if it helps :)